# Prevent position absolute element from sticking inside scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having this issue with multiple items (e.g. a color picker, date picker, and a time picker) where when they pop out and are thus positioned absolute relative to the input, if a user scrolls the newly spawned element also moves with it.

Based on the nature of most plugins (all major bootstrap plugins I've noticed do this) I'm trying to think of a way to target and keep these elements fixed relative to their original location without hacking every plugin if possible.

Below is an example of the issue in which I utilized the bootstrap datepicker. Click on input to spawn datepicker and then scroll and notice the datepicker staying relative to the screen not the input.

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GuJR6/1/

Thanks!

```
.container {
    margin-top: 15px;
    height:400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.scrolling-content {
    height:1000px;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="scrolling-content">
        <div class="well text-center">
            <input type="text" class="datetimepicker" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just [forked bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/marionebl/bootstrap-datetimepicker/tree/container-option) and added the `container` option mention by Jan Peapke. You can use it like this:

```
$(selector).datetimepicker({ container: nativeDOMElement });
$(selector).datetimepicker({ container: jQueryObject });
$(selector).datetimepicker({ container: jQuerySelector });
```

This allows you to solve your problem:

**In your css:**

```
.scrolling-content {
    position: relative;
}
```

Compare: [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

**js**

```
$(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({  
         format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',
         container: '.scrolling-content'
     });
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/GuJR6/2/

The first input in the fiddle applies the explained fix for your issue. The second should behave like before.

**Related pull request**

https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/pull/215

Comment: Nice work! This is something that could easily be added to any existing plugins I'm using. If you trolled github for bootstrap plugins you'll find a lot missing this option that's native of the bootstrap core plugins. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Finally got this working with your help.. after spending a lot of time trying different things.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the problem lies with the bootstrap datetimepicker itself.
Instead of attaching it to the same container as the input, it is attached to the body.

I looked up the documentation to see if there is an option to set the parent, but I'm afraid there is not.

As a solution you could try another framework, like [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/).

You could also try to correct the position of the picker manually by attaching a click handler to the input field that removes the datepicker from the body, adds it to the content of the scrollcontainer and uses the events mouse coordinates to position it correctly inside the container. Seems like a lot of hassle though. :)

regards,
J

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, seen the container option within a few docs I'll give that a go.

Comment: If there is an option please make sure to post it here for future reference. :)

Comment: Will do, playing around with a few options. Will update when I find something that'll work.

Comment: @d3c0y any change in this? The `bootstrap datepicker` plugin supports "container" - does `datetimepicker` still not?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('YOURCLASSNAME').on('scroll', function () {
        var $this = $('.input-group.date');
        $this.datepicker('place');
    });
```

Add above code before

```
Datepicker.prototype = {...}
```

*This is the solution. and works fine on all devices and screen sizes*

Comment: datepicker('place') is perfect ! Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Even i have been facing this issue. 
Found out a solution to this By adding var t;

```
    $('YOURCLASSNAME').on('scroll', function () {
        var $this = $('.input-group.date');
        window.clearTimeout(t);
        t = window.setTimeout(function () {
            $this.datepicker('place');
        }, 50)
    });
```

Add above code  after  `if (showFocus)     this.show();`
in this block 
var Datepicker = function (element, options) {....} of **bootstrap-datepicker.js plugin**